# php-vcr will break autoload of PHPUnit

Tags: phpunit, php-vcr

Enabling php-vcr in PHPUnit bootstrap file breaks the autoloading of class PHPUnit\Framework\ExceptionWrapper

I tried to downgrade PHPUnit to 7.x without success. Removing VCR from bootstrap solves the ExceptionWrapper issue

Here's the beginning of my bootstrap file

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

use VCR\VCR;

VCR::turnOn();
VCR::configure()->setMode('new_episodes');
```

PHPUnit configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/6.1/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
>
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="unit">
            <directory>tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="integration">
            <directory>tests/Integration</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="end2end">
            <directory>tests/End2End</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>src</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

Expected: successful tests

Actual:

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit --color=always --verbose --testsuite=integration
PHPUnit 8.1.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.3.4 with Xdebug 2.7.2
Configuration: /var/www/project/phpunit.xml.dist

............................
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\ExceptionWrapper' not found in /var/www/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php on line 732

Error: Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\ExceptionWrapper' not found in /var/www/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php on line 732

Call Stack:
    0.0002     422288   1. {main}() /var/www/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:0
    0.0224    1925752   2. PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main() /var/www/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:61
    0.0224    1925864   3. PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->run() /var/www/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:163
    0.1295    6797680   4. PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner->doRun() /var/www/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:207
    0.1456    7214088   5. PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run() /var/www/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php:613
    0.1463    7214280   6. PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run() /var/www/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:761
    0.6619   12277352   7. PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run() /var/www/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:761
    0.6629   12277544   8. PHPUnit\Framework\DataProviderTestSuite->run() /var/www/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:761
    0.8272   18014088   9. EasyWelfare\Tests\Integration\Routes\AvailabilityTest->run() /var/www/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:761
    0.8272   18014088  10. PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult->run() /var/www/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php:808
```

Hint: the test that breaks involves SoapClient

Comment: Place a breakpoint on that line and check what happened to the auto-loader. php-vcr can set a file:// stream wrapper that might run into a problem here reporting the missing class's file inexistent while it's just on disk. Also [php-vcr examples](https://github.com/php-vcr/php-vcr/blob/378033762ca95e89d9f371c2ae3a58e1e2b030db/tests/integration/soap/test/bootstrap.php) suggest to turn off after on directly (no configure call).